Nestjs not injecting service to controller
I'm migrating a backend to serverless and want to keep my current nestjs setup for now, but I'm having an issue that prevents me to run usecases/services (they're the same I just call them differently to follow clean architecture rather than nestjs conventions)
So when the code reaches to the controller, it is not injecting anything and it throws an error as the usecase field is undefined.
I have this code:
app.module.ts
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
    }),
    OrdersModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}

controller.ts
@Controller('order')
export class OrderController {
  constructor(private readonly createOrderUseCase: CreateOrderUseCase) {}

  @Post('create')
  async createOrder(@Body() orderData: CreateOrderDto): Promise<void> {
    await this.createOrderUseCase.execute(orderData);

    return;
  }

  @Get('orders')
  async getOrders(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('INFO - Getting orders');
    return 'Orders';
  }
}

orders.module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([OrderEntity])],
  controllers: [OrderController],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'EventRepository', useClass: SqsRepository },
    { provide: 'OrderRepository', useClass: OrderRepositoryImpl },
    CreateOrderUseCase,
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class OrdersModule {}

And this is the lambda handler, which is the entrypoint for all the lambdas (I know this has to be changed but don't have the time right now to change all of it to a proper serverless setup)
let cachedServer: Handler;

async function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Handler> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    console.log('INFO - Bootstrapping server');
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    console.log('INFO - Nest application created');
    await nestApp.init();
    console.log('INFO - Nest application initialized');
    const expressApp = nestApp.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
    cachedServer = serverless(expressApp, { binary: [] });
    console.log('INFO - Server created');
  }

  console.log('INFO - Returning cached server');
  return cachedServer;
}

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback,
) => {
  cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  console.log('INFO - Proxying request to server');
  return cachedServer(event, context, callback);
};

Any ideas?

please share us the whole error message.

full error message

The error message is not giving any insight, it just says that the usecase field inside the controller is undefined, so it throws an error when trying to execute the usecase method, all this happens because it is not injecting the dependencies properly but I do not know why.
